# SharePoint 2010 - Calculated column - IF statement with (OR) not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, calculated-column

I have the following entered as formula in a Calculated column (returns single line of text)...
I'm going to add to the formula, but it's stuck on this point; takes me to error page:

```
=IF(
OR(
LEFT([EVENT TYPE],8)="Mtng (PM", 
LEFT([EVENT TYPE],8)="Mtng (eP", 
LEFT([EVENT TYPE],8)="Mtng (DS",
LEFT([EVENT TYPE],8)="Mtng (#D"
), 
"Fill DC columns",
"N/A for this row"
)
```

This works fine in Excel when I change column name to a cell in Excel.
The column "EVENT TYPE" is a choice column.

-------Update----------

I tested created a new Event Type column using same settings as for initial. The formula works in new column (on the right), but not the original one (left). Can anyone please explain why?

[image: Column Setting Comparison]

Comment: Is it a multiple choice column?  What's the error message in SharePoint?

Comment: Checkboxes will not work with Calculated Columns.

Comment: Error: "One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas."

Comment: It is a choice column with dropdown. Does not allow multiple choices. Single response only.

Comment: Recheck the column type, and create a new Choice column and test with it. Your formula works in my SP2010 just fine. The error message is consistent with a multiple choices / checkbox Choice column.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Checked and result in my edited post. Can you please help explain why formula not working with original column when settings all the same?

Comment: A bug? :-)   Was the data in the list of choices the same in both?

Comment: Mike, I copy/pasted the list of choices from initial column to create dropdown for second (test) column and then used dropdown to populate few cells for testing purposes. So similar data from same list of choices.